# Загружается скрипт php вместо файла pdf

Tags: php, mysql

В MySQL таблице создал колонку,которая хранит в себе путь к файлу на локальном диске и вместо того, чтобы скачивать файл по ссылке,скачивается сам скрипт php.

```
echo "<a href='" .$i['Книга']. "'download>Сюда</a>
```

Вот путь :  C:\WebServers\home\digitallibrary.ru\www\books\Pushkin_A_Ruslan_I_Lyudmila.a6.pdf

Comment: Дайте больше информации, как путь прописали . И зачем download ?
Вот что вам нужно получить <a href="/pdf/book1.pdf">TEXT</a>

Comment: Атрибут download необходим чтобы скачать книгу по ссылке.

Comment: а что если в тэге `<a>` просто путь к файлу указан он не скачивается больше?

Comment: В таком случае,книга будет одна и та же.

Comment: Не забыли ли вы перед `download` поставить вопросительный знак?  `echo "<a href='" .$i['Книга']. "'?download>Сюда</a>`

Comment: Нет,не помогло.